# Generar conexiones mysql desde una función

Tags: mysql, vb.net

espero estén bien. 
Quisiera saber si puede pasar (como un parámetro) un conector mysql por dentro de una función. Esto en vb.net.
Es posible?
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si, podés recibir por parámetro un conector Mysql.

Acordate de incluir tener instalado el paquete MySql.Data y declarar que vas a recibir el tipo de parámetro MySqlConnection, te quedaría algo así:

```
using MySql.Data

Protected Sub miConsulta(conector As MySqlConnection)
      Dim adaptador As MySqlDataAdapter
      Dim comandos As MySqlCommandBuilder
      Dim EstadoConexion As Boolean = False
      conector = New MySqlConnection(CONEXION)
      conector.Open()
      'etc..
End Sub
```

Saludos!